# Calculate minimal changeset between two DOM nodes or jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, dom, handlebars.js

I want to calculate a minimal changeset between two DOM nodes or jQuery object.

The brackground is that right now I'm using handlebars to update the DOM.

When calling the render method, I do something like this:

```
$el.empty().append(handlebarTemplate(model));
```

But I would like to change only those things that changed. Like a string or a subtree gets replaced by another, etc.

So for example tha template would be like:

```
<div>
    <span>Hi there <a href="#">{{name}}</a>.</span>
</div>
```

And the `name` would be `John` and it changes to `Mary`, I don't want the whole `<div>` to get replaced, but only the text inside the `<a>`-Node.

But I'm not quite sure how this could be done. Are there any open sources libraries out there for this kind of job? Or what would be the basic idea to get this done?

Comment: This might not be worth it, comparing the nodes might take longer than simply replacing everything. Are you having problems with the current method?

Comment: Well I just would like to have a more stable DOM, you know? Because I'm managing lots of capsuled components, that all have a partial DOM and when some variable gets updated, this whole DOM part will be updated. I saw that ember.js seems to only replace the changed parts.

Comment: Do you already have an indication that the model data changed? With that in place, it would be a matter of using `$el.find('span a').html(newName)`. In Backbone, for example, you could solve that by having the view listen to model change events on specific fields.

Comment: You should take a look at the [React library](http://facebook.github.io/react/). Even if you don't want/can use it directly, it does exactly what you want (calculating a diff of a particular DOM subtree to determine minimum number of DOM manipualtions to apply those changes to the DOM).

Comment: @bfavaretto But how do I know where that `name` is referenced in the compiled Handlebars template?

Comment: Hm, it sounds like you're looking for something more generic than I thought. Perhaps Daniel's suggestion above? I can't say, never used react.